# How to dynamic update the adapter for activities?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am working on an app which combines the SQL and the adapter. The main issue is that once I updated the database, the adapter will not reflect my update directly. Here's the code:

```
public class RSSItemActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rssitem);

        long channelid = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(RSSReaderApp.CHANNEL_KEY);
        DBAdaptor dbAdaptor = ((RSSReaderApp)getApplication()).getDBAdaptor();
        Cursor cursor = dbAdaptor.getRssItems(channelid);

        adapter = new RSSItemAdapter(this, R.layout.rssitemview, cursor);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

As you can see, this code get the data from the SQL at the line `Cursor cursor = dbAdaptor.getRssItems(channelid);`(The get RssItems is just loading data we want to present on the screen from the SQL). However, I have some bottoms in the same activity that if I press that, it will change the values in the SQL, which should affect the data it retrieve. (For example, there's a column decide what's these item's color, it is originally set to white, after I press that, it should be blue.) However, once I press that, seems although the data in the SQL is changed, but the real presentation is still the same color. I had tried using `adapter.swapCursor(dbAdapter.getRssItems(id));` on the bottom to update the cursor everytime I press the buttom, but it will let my original display disappear (Possibly because the original adapter loses it's cursor,so it can display nothing), I have to reload that page to get the correct output. Is there a way that I can instantly update the output? Thanks for your reply in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update the cursor in the adapter. You could call the following:

```
// Closes the old cursor as well.
adapter.changeCursor(dbAdapter.getRssItems(id)); 
// Notify the view that the underlying data has changed.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, the difference with swapCursor() is that changeCursor, automatically closes the old cursor, while swapCursor does not.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that, it seems that it will work for first few times, then the result become strange.(I still lost the output after several clicks) The way I actually do is I will open a new intent, and display new stuff. When I go back to the list, it works for first time, but when I press the link to another page and get back, it's just broken. A little bit strange, but still thanks

Comment: Did you override onResume() (and onPause())?  If you activity a new Activity with an intent your current activity will be paused and the state will be lost. In the onResume() you might want to load the data again from the database.

Comment: I didn't do that, so I should override onResume() and ask it to load the data again? so everytime I come back to this page it can make sure the result is most updated?

Comment: The program just crashed after I added onResume(). The current issue seems like I should figure out that starting an intent will only pause this process, which brings problems to me now.

Comment: It shouldn't crash. Have you looked at LogCat what the error was?

Comment: Hmm, now it won't crashed (Just fixed it). I added `
  DBAdaptor dbAdapter = ((RSSReaderApp)getApplication()).getDBAdaptor();
  adapter.changeCursor(dbAdapter.getRssItems(nowid));
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); `
in the onPause. No matter I added this adapter change stuff on the bottom or here, it follows the same pattern.
When I just install this app
Listview(Correct)->GotoIntent(Correct)->GobacktoView(Correct)->GotoAnotherIntent(Correct)->GobacktoView(Wrong, nothing here), after this, everytime I restart the app, it becomes Listview(Correct)->GotoIntent(Correct)->GobacktoView(Wrong)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
runOnUiThread(returnResult);


private Runnable returnResult = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(array_list.size() > 0)
        {
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<array_list.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(array_list.get(i));
        }
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
  };
```